# How redirect to homepage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using MVC. I am showing Thank you page(view) after user reset his password. I like to redirect to Home page by clicking anywhere in page,( I am not allow to use jquery only JavaScript) 
  This is a method that return Thank you page view:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("resetpassword")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel resetPasswordViewModel)
    {
        string email = resetPasswordViewModel.Email;
        string token = Request["token"].ToString();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (resetPasswordViewModel.Password == resetPasswordViewModel.ConfirmPassword)
            {
                var user = Task.Run(() => Service.GetUserByEmailAsync(email)).Result;
                if (user != null)
                {
                    userRequest.Id = user.FirstOrDefault().Id;
                    userRequest.Password = resetPasswordViewModel.Password;
                    userRequest.Token = token;
                    await Service.UpdateUserAsync(userRequest);
                }
            }
            else
      //stay in same view and show error if there is any
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please enter the same value again.");
                  return View(resetPasswordViewModel);
            }
        }
          else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Password is Required Field.");
            return View(resetPasswordViewModel);
        }
        //in case on success toes to ThankYouResetPassword view
        return View("ThankYouResetPassword");
    }
```

and this is ThankYouResetPassword View that is JavaScript Modal:

```
<div id="ThankYou-Page" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <div id="forgot">
        <div class="modal-heading">Forgot Password?</div>
        <hr class="forgot-password-line" />
        <br />
        <p>An email has been sent to you with the password reset link.</p>
        <br />       
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the box displays you could add an event listener to the body of the page.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.location.replace('redirectPage.html');
}
```

We want to use **location.replace** because we don't want them to hit refresh or back and resubmit the form. This is less of an issue with modern browsers, but it's still worth protecting against.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

> window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com/homepage";

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a onclick attribute ?

```
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content" onclick="window.location.href='/'">
<span class="close">x</span>
<div id="forgot">
    <div class="modal-heading">Forgot Password?</div>
    <hr class="forgot-password-line" />
    <br />
    <p>An email has been sent to you with the password reset link.</p>
    <br />       
</div>
</div>
```